# Is my classifier having memory leaks or other memory-related issues? If yes, how do I address them?

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, neural-network, pytorch, face-recognition

I'm running a classifier for face recognition implemented by arsfutura that you can find at https://github.com/arsfutura/face-recognition, based on pytorch. I'm using ubuntu 18.04 in a 64bit artchitecture, python 3.6.8. Please tell me if there is some additional information that can be useful to address my issue, I will provide it.
I run the face recognition via webcam using the command

`mprof run video_classifier.py`

by running the script this way, a file with extention .dat is compiled in the current directory, and by plotting this file using

`mprof plot file.dat`

I get something like this:
[used memory vs. time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ypGu.png)

Waiting more time, the used memory will slowly but steadily increase. Does this mean there is a memory leak or some other memory-related problem? How can I be sure? How can I figure out why and where this is happening?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Author of Ars Futura Face Recognition library here.

There is a memory leak in `facenet-pytorch` dependency that we use, check out this [issue](https://github.com/timesler/facenet-pytorch/issues/57). As soon as `facenet-pytorch` fixes this issue I'll update our library with the fix. I believe this will be soon.

Comment: So, did they fix that?